# Getting a CMake Error: Cannot specify link libraries for target which is not built by the project

Tags: cmake

I am implementing CMake in my code but I'm getting the error

```
Cannot specify link libraries for target "Qt5::Widgets" which is not built by the project
```

Below are the contents of the CMakeLists.txt:

```
#Specify the version being used aswell as the language
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

#Name your project here
project(eCAD)

#Sends the -std=c++11 flag to the gcc compiler
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-std=c++11)

#This tells CMake to main.cpp and name it eCAD
add_executable(eCAD main.cpp)


#include the subdirectory containing our libs
add_subdirectory (gui)
include_directories(gui)

#include Qt directories
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt5Core)
find_package(Qt5Designer)
SET(QT_USE_QTDESIGNER ON)

#link_libraries
target_link_libraries(Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core)
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The first argument of `target_link_libraries` is the target name:

```
target_link_libraries(eCAD Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core)
```

Answer (score 120):

In addition to the accepted answer: An important detail is to place `target_link_libraries` **after** the `add_executable` **and** `find_package` lines, so all linked components are known.

Comment: what about the target... how do define your target then?

Comment: @Lamda Your question doesn't make sense to me, and this thread isn't about specifying the target but about linking against it. If you've got a specific problem you should consider searching SO and creating a new question if necessary.

Comment: My question was regarding this comment, which seemed to be well received but a bit odd to me.  when you link your libraries, you link it to a target.  add_executable would define the target. So how would you link to something that isn't defined yet?.. And sorry for bringing up an  old topic (just wanted to learn something new...)

Comment: Read everything in context, first the question, then wRAR's answer, then mine. They address exactly this problem.

Comment: ohh.. Sorry.. I seem to have misread your answer.  My initial thought was that you wanted to do it the other way ( link first then add_executable), hence my initial confusion, but you've  written the exact opposite, which makes more sense.

Comment: This was exactly the problem I had. Once tartget_link_libraries came at the end of my CMake.txt it was fine. Great tip!

Answer (score 12):

Also, do not confuse **target** name with the **project** name:

- a command `project` specifies a **project** name, but
- a **target** is the one created with `add_executable`, `add_library` or `add_custom_target`.

The error message is about the **target**.

Answer (score -4):

Set `you_lib_name` before setting `target_link_libraries`

```
set(you_lib_name libname)
target_link_libraries(you_lib_name Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core)
```

Comment: Either your intention or code is wrong. `set` command defines the **variable**, but `target_link_libraries` wants the **target**. In CMake variables and targets are completely **unrelated** things.