# CMake build with linking dlib failed

Tags: linux, cmake, clion, dlib

I need to use dlopen and other linking functions. I am making CodeHunt in C++.

I am using CLion for the project. This is the cmake that I appened the last line to:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(CodeHunt)


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES
        levels/levels.cpp
        levels/levels.hpp
        user/solution.cpp
        user/solution.hpp
        codehunt.cpp
        codeloader.hpp
        integerlevel.hpp
        level.hpp)

add_executable(CodeHunt ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
```

And this is the error I get:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "dl" which is not built by this
  project.
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a CMake Error: Cannot specify link libraries for target which is not built by the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909943/getting-a-cmake-error-cannot-specify-link-libraries-for-target-which-is-not-bui)

Comment: As said in the answer to duplicate question, the first argument to `target_link_libraries` is the target which you want to link with. In your case it is `CodeHunt`.

Comment: This is the answer, Thank you Tsyvarev.

Answer (score 0):

```
target_link_libraries(CodeHunt ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
```

is the solution... :)
It should have been obvious for some experts from the

```
"..which is not built by this project."
```

line, but whateva.
Thanks to [Tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev)