# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 on mac os Mojave, using CLion as IDE

Tags: c++, macos, clion

My cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(vd3)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
include_directories(/usr/local/include)

add_executable(vd3 main.cpp)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sbml/SBMLTypes.h>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SBMLDocument* document = readSBML(argv[1]);
    unsigned int errors = document->getNumErrors();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "  filename: " << argv[1] << endl;
    cout << "  error(s): " << errors  << endl;
    cout << endl;
    if (errors > 0) document->printErrors(cerr);
    return errors;
}
```

Output

```
g++ -lm main.cpp -o main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"SBMLDocument::printErrors(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, 
std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const", referenced from:
  _main in main-98f75f.o
"SBMLDocument::getNumErrors() const", referenced from:
  _main in main-98f75f.o
"_readSBML", referenced from:
  _main in main-98f75f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: You have to link against the `sbml` library.

Comment: I have the sbml header files in the /usr/local/include directory. Isn't that sufficient?

Comment: If sbml would be a header only library then it would be sufficient that all headers are found. A missing header would be a compiler error. But a `Undefined symbols for architecture` is a linking error, and as of that you need to link against that library.

Comment: Dynamically-linked - libsbml.5.dylib

Statically-linked - libsbml.a

Libtool control file - libsbml.la

I have these 3 files too. Which one do I need to use? And should I link it in the above cmake file?

Comment: `target_link_libraries(vd3 /usr/local/lib/libsbml.5.dylib)` is the simplest thing that could work, but it is not very portable.

Comment: The easiest thing is to do static linking because you don't need to make sure that the dylib can be found when the application is launched. (But in your case it most certainly won't make a difference if you link against `.a` or `.dylib`) And you link your executable against the lib in your cmake file using `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: @Botje: Tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: @t.niese: This is what my cmake looks like now: 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(vd3)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
include_directories(/usr/local/include)

target_link_libraries(vd3 /usr/local/lib/libsbmlsim-static.a)
add_executable(vd3 main.cpp)

This results in /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /Users/studentuser/CLionProjects/vd3
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "vd3" which is not built by this
  project.

Comment: You have to define the target first before you can `target_link_libraries` to it.

Comment: [Getting a CMake Error: Cannot specify link libraries for target which is not built by the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909943/getting-a-cmake-error-cannot-specify-link-libraries-for-target-which-is-not-bui/41262868) and [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @Botje Updated cmake: 

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(vd3)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
include_directories(/usr/local/include)


add_executable(vd3 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(vd3 /usr/local/lib/libsbmlsim-static.a)

Same initial "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:" error

Comment: This is sbml*sim*. Did you verify that this contains the proper symbols? `otool -tv` can tell you.

Comment: @Botje: Running otool -tv libsbmlsim-static.a printed long assembly code. Regarding verifying the package, I did remove and reinstall the library using the .dmg file

Comment: Oh, duh. Wrong tool. `nm` should tell you what is inside the .a file. If it does not contain `readSBML` you are linking with the wrong library.

Comment: But why do you link against `libsbmlsim-static.a` and not against the `libsbml.a`? `libsbmlsim-static.a` belongs to [github: libsbmlsim/libsbmlsim](https://github.com/libsbmlsim/libsbmlsim), but the missing symbols are from `libsbml`.

Comment: @t.niese i checked for all the files created in the /usr/local/lib directly, after running the dmg installer for the library(http://sbml.org/Software/libSBML/5.17.0/docs//cpp-api/libsbml-installation.html). These are the files it creates: libsbmlsim-static.a     libsbmlsim.1.4.0.dylib  libsbmlsim.1.4.dylib    libsbmlsim.dylib

Comment: Yes but before that you talked about `libsbml.5.dylib`,  `libsbml.a` and `libsbml.la` then shown error is about `libsbml` and not about `libsbmlsim`.

Comment: @t.niese: Yes, because that's what the documentation says(http://sbml.org/Software/libSBML/5.17.0/docs//cpp-api/libsbml-installation.html)- section 3. I am not sure what lead to this discrepency in file naming

Comment: As I said `libsbmlsim.1.4.dylib` belongs to a different library, it belongs to libsbmlsim (version 1.4). You have to install libsbml, and link against that library.

Comment: @t.niese Thanks, got it working!