# CMake Static Library linking (Precompiled .a)

Tags: c++, cmake, static, esp32, precompiled

I've been dealing with this problem day and night for a week. I've read every page on Google, Stackoverflow and Github.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED OFF)
include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)
project(EDKPOC)

add_library(BCXConfiguration STATIC IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(BCXConfiguration PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main/liBCXConfiguration.a"
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main/include")

link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

target_link_libraries(EDKPOC BCXConfiguration)
```

**It gives this error when I run CMake:**

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "EDKPOC" which is not built
  by this project.
```

Comment: What is this file meant to do? `add_library` builds a library, but then you try to link that library to something else?

Comment: While the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909943/getting-a-cmake-error-cannot-specify-link-libraries-for-target-which-is-not-bui) *initially* did't contain the answer to your problem, I have added that answer. Having different problems with the **same error message** under the single title (in the **single question**) would help future visitors to find resolution for their problem more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command is used to link a given target with its dependent targets. You specify `EDKPOC` as the first argument to the command; this is your project name, but it is not a valid **target**. The only target you've specified in your example CMake file is `BCXConfiguration`. If you want to link this static library to another target (e.g. `MyOtherLibraryTarget`) elsewhere in your CMake project, your syntax could look something like this:

```
target_link_libraries(MyOtherLibraryTarget PUBLIC BCXConfiguration)
```

If you don't have other targets in your CMake hierarchy, then this command is unnecessary and can be left out.

Comment: thanks but  this brought me another error. when I use this linked BCXConfiguration.a file. I've referenced BCXConfiguration.h file and use class in this file and BEDK::BCXConfiguration *bcx = new BEDK::BCXConfiguration(); and give undefined reference error

Comment: @MesutA.: Please, update the question post with description of the new problem. This description should include your updated `CMakeLists.txt`. It is difficult to catch the error in the file we don't see.