# CMAKE GLFW linking problems

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, glfw

I wanto add glfw dependency by cmake in CLion but i get weird error, this is the `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(hello_gl)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(hello_gl glfw)


add_executable(hello_gl main.cpp)
```

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (target_link_libraries):
Cannot specify link libraries for target "hello_gl" which is not built by
this project.
```

This is the error I get? How it comes that cmake cannot find my app?

Comment: [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41262868/3440745) to the duplicate question resolves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I tried to link glfw lib after adding the executable

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(hello_gl)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(hello_gl main.cpp)

find_package(glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(hello_gl glfw)
```

Here is the right CMakeLists.txt