# Linking opengl in cmake

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, glfw

I'm trying to link opengl32 to my project through cmake. I tried

```
set(LIBS "opengl32.dll" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/GLFW/include")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBS})
```

but when I tried to run the program, it gives me `unresolved external symbol _glfwInit referenced in function ...`

Comment: What is the compiler? With msvc / Visual Studio you don't link dlls you link the `.lib` (import library) that goes with the dll.

Comment: `set(LIBS "opengl32.dll" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/GLFW/include")` line seems quite odd when passed to `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBS})` the include folder has nothing to do with linking.

Comment: Your CMakeLists.txt should be similar to this: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/64952671/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64952671/487892)