# How to add lib.a static library into my project without add_library() using cmake?

Tags: cmake, clion

I already have a lib.a. I just want to linking this lib into my project. I tried to use `find_library()` and `target_link_library()` how shown in this tutorial [https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-cmake-tutorial.html#static-libs][tutorial] . But when I write this `find_library(SRC_INsddfsdfT lib/src_intfdssfd libsdfsdfsd)`
`target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} LINK_PUBLIC /lib/libsrc_ini_lib.a)` from step 6. I have find then method find_library() always isn't working. I can write any strings in it and this method does't get errors. However method terget_link_library() always does got me 1 error `Cannot specify link libraries for target "RightTests" which is not built by`
this project.

Please help me with this trouble.

P.S. I don't how to linking library without sequence inside add_library(${LIB_NAME} STATIC ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

Comment: By the line `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} LINK_PUBLIC /lib/libsrc_ini_lib.a)` you attempt to link a library with the target named "RightTests" (assuming this is a name of your project). It is implied, that the target "RightTests" is created by previous `add_executable` or `add_library` call. Please, show the code which creates that target. See also the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909943/getting-a-cmake-error-cannot-specify-link-libraries-for-target-which-is-not-bui) about meaning of the error message you got.

Comment: RightTests is the project name. I have a folder which contents folders from sources and headers. It's library from sources. Third day I can't linking it in my project

Comment: Actually, there is no such thing like "linking a **project** to the library". You could only link to the library an **executable** or (another) **library**. You probably need to read some tutorial about CMake. E.g. that one: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html.

Comment: The more appropriate `add_library` command would be `add_library(name_of_the_lib STATIC IMPORTED)`, but you need to set some properties before you can link this lib to another one via `target_link_libraries`; note that e.g. for `target_include_directories` you need to use `INTERFACE` visibility for imported libs. More on imported liibs here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries

Comment: If you know where the library is located you can also use `target_link_directories` and `target_link_libraries`